# All intersections in Interval Binary Search Tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

So I am trying to implement an algorithm to walk through an interval search tree and find all intersections. I was able to create and insert nodes with no problem, but the algorithm I have to walk through the tree currently only searches for any one interval that intersects the query interval. As an example, if (21, 23) was passed as the query parameter, the tree would find the node 16, 22 as an intersection, but disregard the node currently to the right of the root node. Any ideas on how I can make an algorithm to find EACH node the query intersects with???

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce4e40e9d9e4af27d66690dcc16245a3

Updated version that checks for all intersections

I decided to remove nodes when they are found in the algorithm that checks for an intersection until it returns null.

https://gist.github.com/DandroidDeveloper/009717551e3785cde48a53ffdeded7d1

```
function checkIntersection(interval, tree){
var currentNode = tree.root;
var intersection = {};
while(currentNode){

    console.log("Searching...", currentNode);
    if (currentNode.list.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < currentNode.list.length; i++){
            if (interval[0] < currentNode.list[i].interval[1] && currentNode.list[i].interval[0] < interval[1]){
                intersection.interval = currentNode.list[i].interval;
                intersection.id = currentNode.list[i].id;
                tree.remove(currentNode.list[i].interval, currentNode.list[i].id);
                return intersection;
            }
        }
    }
    if (interval[0] < currentNode.interval[1] && currentNode.interval[0] < interval[1]){
        console.log("INTERSECTION: "+interval, currentNode.interval);
        intersection.interval = currentNode.interval;
        intersection.id = currentNode.id;
        tree.remove(currentNode.interval, currentNode.id);
        return intersection;
    }
    if (!currentNode.left){
        console.log("NO NODE TO LEFT, GO RIGHT");
        if (!currentNode.right){
            console.log("NO MORE NODES");
            return null;
        }
        console.log(currentNode.right);
        currentNode = currentNode.right;
    }
    else if (currentNode.left.max < interval[0]){
        console.log("LEFT MAX: "+currentNode.left.max+" < "+interval[0]+" GO RIGHT");
        currentNode = currentNode.right;
    }
    else{
        console.log("INTERVAL MAY BE TO LEFT, GO LEFT");
        currentNode = currentNode.left;
    }
}
}

function checkAllIntersections(interval, tree){
var intersections = [];
var flag = true;
while(flag){
    var temp = checkIntersection(interval, tree);
    if (!temp){
        flag = false;
    }
    else{
        intersections.push(temp);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < intersections.length; i++){
    tree.add(intersections[i].interval, intersections[i].id);
}
return intersections;
```

}

Comment: So currently I am working on going through the tree and simply deleting the intersecting nodes and adding them to an array..... If anyone has a better suggestion let me know!

Comment: In other words, create tree, search for intersections, if you find one, push it to an array, remove it from the tree, and recurse until there are no intersections, then insert all nodes in array back into tree....

Comment: Please provide the algorithm you currently use to search the tree. It can probably be modified to return more than one node - but people need to see the algorithm itself to help you with it.

Comment: Here is the updated version I made, I think so far it only errors out if you query an interval with a start and end time that are equal, still toying around with it though 

https://gist.github.com/DandroidDeveloper/009717551e3785cde48a53ffdeded7d1

Comment: Can you please provide the algorithm you use (pseudocode or explanations) for the specific part that is in question (here - the logics of searching and returning nodes using a given section) rather than linking the whole code? If you want to give the actual code - please copy only the relevant part into the question's body itself (here - probably the functions `checkIntersection` and `checkAllIntersections`).

Comment: It's just the generic algorithm to check if an intersection exists, but I remove the node each time I find one and call it until it returns null if that helps. Because the max value of each subtree is stored in a node, if the queries start value is greater than the max, it knows not to look in that subtree

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is construct an array of objects while going over the tree and return that array at the end instead of returning only the first find you have. Here's your code altered in such a way:

```
function checkIntersection(interval, tree){
var currentNode = tree.root;
var intersection = {};
var intersections = []; //array to return multiple objects
while(currentNode){

    console.log("Searching...", currentNode);
    if (currentNode.list.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < currentNode.list.length; i++){
            if (interval[0] < currentNode.list[i].interval[1] && currentNode.list[i].interval[0] < interval[1]){
                intersection.interval = currentNode.list[i].interval;
                intersection.id = currentNode.list[i].id;
                //---DELETE---tree.remove(currentNode.list[i].interval, currentNode.list[i].id); no need to remove
                intersections.push(intersection); //add the newly found intersection to the returned array
                intersection = {}; //prepare the variable for next find
            }
        }
    }
    if (interval[0] < currentNode.interval[1] && currentNode.interval[0] < interval[1]){
        console.log("INTERSECTION: "+interval, currentNode.interval);
        intersection.interval = currentNode.interval;
        intersection.id = currentNode.id;
        //again no need to remove
        intersections.push(intersection);
        intersection = {};
    }
    if (!currentNode.left){
        console.log("NO NODE TO LEFT, GO RIGHT");
        if (!currentNode.right){
            console.log("NO MORE NODES");
            return intersections;
        }
        console.log(currentNode.right);
        currentNode = currentNode.right;
    }
    else if (currentNode.left.max < interval[0]){
        console.log("LEFT MAX: "+currentNode.left.max+" < "+interval[0]+" GO RIGHT");
        currentNode = currentNode.right;
    }
    else{
        console.log("INTERVAL MAY BE TO LEFT, GO LEFT");
        currentNode = currentNode.left;
    }
}
```

Note that this code will traverse the whole tree for each search even if the intersections are only in the leftmost leaf of the tree. To change that you can add checks at the end (similar to the check you have now not to get into subtrees with too low max-values) to avoid going into subtrees with too high minimum-values for the queried interval:

```
if (interval[1] < currentNode.right.value){ //no intersections possible in the right subtree
    return intersections;
} else {
    currentNode = currentNode.right;
}
```

just use this snippet wherever you now have: `currentNode = currentNode.right;`